# Lost precision when selecting columns with calculations under Android

Tags: android, sql, ormlite

I have different columns in a database. I use ormlite and I execute a SQL with a `genericRawResults`. My code is like:

```
GenericRawResults<Total> rawResults =
    dao.queryRaw("select items*3 from Items", new RawRowMapper<Total>() {
        public Total mapRow(String[] columnNames,
            String[] resultColumns) throws SQLException {
                   return new Total(new BigDecimal(resultColumns[0]));
        }
        });
```

The result is a number which has lost decimals. Why?

I try to use cast(columnname as REAL) but the result is the same.  What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your schema and can you show the string result that you are mapping?

Comment: My schema is: <br> CREATE TABLE Items (`factory` VARCHAR NOT NULL, 'd1' VARCHAR NOT NULL, 'd2' VARCHAR NOT NULL, 'id' INTEGER NOT NULL, 'price' VARCHAR NOT NULL, 'item' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT) </br>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!!!!! I convert Real to Varchar like this:

`select id, factory, cast( SUM(Round((cast(Round((cast(price as REAL))*(cast((100-d1)/cast(100 as REAL) as REAL)),3) as REAL))*
(cast((100-2)/cast(100 as REAL) as REAL)),3)* cast(units as REAL)) as VARCHAR) from Items  group by id, factory`

And I don't lose decimals!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know specifically what is at fault here without seeing the Sqlite schema and without seeing the `String` result of `item*3`.

I suspect that this is not a problem with [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) however.  I suspect that this is a limitation of Sqlite in that it uses a small precision to do internal calculations.  Here's an example from the Sqlite command line:

```
select 11312541243231.01*3;
33937623729693.0  // << note the missing .03
```

I would suggest that you do *not* do the `*3` in your query but rather do the multiplication *after* it has been converted into a `BigDecimal`.  I guess something like:

```
BigDecimal big = new BigDecimal(resultColumns[0]);
big.multiply(new BigDecimal(3));
```

Comment: I have thought about multiply my result at the end but I have a lot of rows and I need to add different rows and for each row I  multiply by a number. It's very slowly.  The sql is like this:  `select id, factory,  SUM(cast(Round((Round((cast((100-d1)/cast(100 as REAL) as REAL)* price),3))*(cast((100-d2)/cast(100 as REAL) as REAL)),3)*cast(units as REAL) as REAL)) from Items  group by id, factory`  I try to multiply by 10000 and after I divide by 10000 but the problem persist. For example If I have _169,794 * 1000 * 12 / 1000 = 2037,53_. But the correct is: _2037,528_

Comment: Not much else I can say @MARM.  Sqlite is doing the arithmetic and it looks to be limited in precision.